Is there a way to make it so hovering over the button only rotates the inside of it?
I am cooking up a design for my website. I have added a settings button and I want to make it the gear icon inside of the button rotates whenever you hover over the button. The only issue is that I don't know how. I've tried looking everywhere for an answer but couldn't find anything that helped.
I've already tried making it so the whole button rotates, which seemed to work, but the gear icon ends up slightly offset from the center.


button {
  width: 8vw;
  height: 8vw;
  border: none;
  background: #353535;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: .5s;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
}

button:hover {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0..1,-50..200" />
<button>
  <span class="material-symbols-outlined">settings</span>
</button>




Making the button not round, for your sample case question, would make things (for the reader) more obvious, no?!

You can target the span within the button for the rotation effects, but still keep the :hover pseudo-class on the button.  For example:


button {
  width: 8vw;
  height: 8vw;
  border: none;
  background: #353535;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
}

button > span {
  transition: .5s;
}

button:hover > span {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0..1,-50..200" />
<button>
  <span class="material-symbols-outlined">settings</span>
</button>




An example where the button is not round, to more easily see:


button {
  width: 8vw;
    height: 8vw;
    border: none;
    background: #353535;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
}

button > span {
    transition: .5s;
}

button:hover > span {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0..1,-50..200" />
<button>
  <span class="material-symbols-outlined">settings</span>
</button>



